# Lockdown command, specifying with guild.roles

Tags: discord.js

I was trying to make a lockdown command, at my point of knowlead, its fine, but something is going wrong.

````
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client  = new Discord.Client();

module.exports = async (msg,client,args) => {
    const channel = msg.channel;
    const roles = msg.guild.roles;

    if(!msg.guild) return;

    if(!msg.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS"))
    msg.channel.send("Você não tem permissão para executar esse comando.")
    else{
        roles.forEach((roles) => {
            channel.overwritePermissions (roles ,{
                SEND_MESSSAGES: false,
                ADD_REACTIONS: false
            })
        })
        msg.channel.send("Canal bloqueado com sucesso.")
    }

}```


**error recived: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined**
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main file you are passing in the arguments as: (client, msg), so in the command file you will need to get the arguments in the right order,

so from:

```js
module.exports = async (msg, client, args) => {
}
```

to this:

```js
module.exports = async (client, msg, args) => {
}
```

also you aren't passing in args in your main file so change from:

```js
if (commands[args[0]]) commands[args[0]](client,msg);
else if(args[0].split("")[0] == config.prefix) unknownCommand(client,msg);
```

To:

```js
const first = args[0];
if(commands[first]) {
   commands[first](client, msg, args);
} else if(first[0] === config.prefix) {
   unknownCommand(client, msg, args);
}
```

The next improvement is in your foreach statement:

```js
roles.forEach((roles) => {
  //code
});
```

Here you have an array of roles and then the variable you are passing is also called roles, you should instead call it role or something else,

Also in v12 `<Message>.guild.roles` is a `Manager` not a collection, so you need to add `.cache

You will also either need to change the parameters in `channel.overwritePermission` or switch to `channel.updateOverwrite`:

```js
roles.cache.forEach(role => {
   channel.updateOverwrite(role, {
      SEND_MESSSAGES: false,
      ADD_REACTIONS: false
   })
})
```

or

```js
roles.cache.forEach(role => {
   channel.overwritePermissions([
    {
        id: role.id,
        deny: ["SEND_MESSAGE", "ADD_REACTIONS"]
    }  
   ]);
})
```

You might also want to look into some better command handlers, currently yours doesn't have any config option for commands from what I can tell

Comment: (node:64776) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

Comment: Can you add the full error message on your post with the info on the lines? if my code didn't fix it that must mean it's in a different code section.

Comment: i cant edit idk why, https://ghostbin.co/paste/qbbh3

Comment: Hmm yea for some reason it is that line, can you log what the msg object is? Add the result to the post, can you also update the old code? Just to make sure you added the if statement correctly

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: https://ghostbin.co/paste/bsfmn    /    https://ghostbin.co/paste/ehxaf respective.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, you are using v12, so instead of `roles.forEach` you need `roles.cache.forEach`

Comment: [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied overwrites is not an Array or Collection of Permission Overwrites.

Comment: im about to give up ;(

Comment: To fix that error use `change.updateOverwrite` instead of `channel.overwritePermissions`, if you want to continue using overwritePermissions I updated the post, if those constant errors are annonying for you, you should probably learn to use discord.js docuemntation

Comment: am i supposed to give the role id on role.id?

Comment: What do you mean? The updated code shows how to do either method. If you mean are you supposed to give the role id on `channel.updateOverwrite`, you can but it's not necessary, the role itself works. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=updateOverwrite

Comment: another error, Invalid bitfield flag or number, btw if you dont want to continue u can drop this, im layman on this, im sorry

Comment: It's fine, send me the current code you have for `roles.cache.forEach(....)`

Comment: Add me on discord so we can stop commenting so much: Karizma#7876

Comment: If anyone is wondering what fixed it, for some reason `@everyone` role doesn't work with `overwitePermissions`, so we just went with updateOverwrite